# YouTube quota limits - what are the best practices?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I am developing an application which relies heavily on the YouTube API to assist in content discovery. During a load  testing phase of development, I received the

```
<domain>yt:quota</domain><code>too_many_recent_calls</code>
```

error a number of times. While the load test was a higher amount of traffic than I am expecting, I would like to hear how people are handling quota issues with the YouTube API. Ideally, I would like to know when I am close to the quota and throttle requests at this point (I would rather present a limited service than '[stop] API calls from your application for 10 minutes after receiving such an error in order to "reset" your quota.' as recommended at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/02/best-practices-for-avoiding-quota.html

Request are GET only, no POST/PUT/DELETE, and there is little demand for instant results (i.e. I can throttle back on the calls made after user interaction if necessary, and present a slower, but fully functional, application)

Has anyone had experience with managing YouTube API calls in this way? Is there a good solution to making requests under the quota, without hitting it and having to back off for 10 minutes to reset?

Answer (score 0):

For v2 'https://developers.google.com/youtube/faq?hl=en#quota'

For v3 'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=en#quota'

should give an idea.

Using v3 and getting users OAuth2 login, will give you the best results generally.